# How to test if coordinates are inside a label or mask

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I'm trying to test which points in a list (numpy array or pandas) are inside a given boolean mask (or labelled image).
I have found way to compare with polygons but not with a mask

From this dataset example how can I test which coords are inside the mask? (best would be to add a column in pandas saying which label they are inside of - that, or add a new column in the "coords" variable saying which label it belongs to).

Masks/labels won't be rectangles in my implementation (basically cell shapes), I'm just doing so here because it's easier.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import numpy as np

coords = np.random.rand(40, 2) *1024
mask = np.zeros((1024,1024))
mask[300:600,50:125] = 1
mask[700:800,400:650] = 2

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.scatter(coords[:,0],coords[:,1],color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321032/python-test-if-point-is-in-rectangle)

Comment: My labels won't be rectangles, sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: Added an answer using shapely to consider any shape.

Comment: I found a way to transform masks to polygons (cellpose.utils.masks_to_outlines).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy indexing of the mask with the coordinates after a bit of massaging.

```py
coords_int = np.round(coords).astype(int)  # or np.floor, depends
values_at_coords = mask[tuple(coords_int.T)]
points_per_value = np.bincount(values_at_coords)
```

Now `points_per_value` contains an array such that `points_per_value[i]` contains the number of coordinates that landed in mask label `i`. ([docs for `np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html))

For more about the second line, you can read about NumPy integer array indexing in the [NumPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

Comment: This is perfect. I hope cupy also works like this.
np.bincount did not work but I fixed with :
values_at_coords = mask[tuple(coords_int.T)].astype(np.int)

values_at_coords is enough as I can add that list as a column in a pandas lista (or list of coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
coords = np.random.rand(40, 2) *1024
mask = np.zeros((1024,1024))
mask[300:600,50:125] = 1
mask[700:800,400:650] = 2
plt.imshow(mask, origin='lower')
plt.scatter(coords[:,1],coords[:,0],color='red')
res = defaultdict(list)
for i in np.unique(mask)[1:]:
    temp = coords[(coords[:, 0] >= (mask == i).nonzero()[0][0]) & (coords[:, 0] <= (mask == i).nonzero()[0][-1])]
    res[i] = temp[(temp[:, 1] >= (mask == i).nonzero()[1][0]) & (temp[:, 1] <= (mask == i).nonzero()[1][-1])]
print(res)
```

Comment: Labels won't be squares. They were just for the example here. Ty for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) to assert whether a point is inside a polygon or not.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
```

Your first mask is defined by the following polygon.

```
polygon = Polygon([(300, 50), (300, 125), (600, 50), (600, 125)])
```

Test for two sample points.

```
point1 = Point(315, 1200)
point2 = Point(315, 75)
print(polygon.contains(point1)) #False
print(polygon.contains(point2)) #True
```

Comment: The output of the machine learning masking is still masks. I can transform each mask into a polygon, but I am trying to look into an efficient way straight from the labels. Thank you for your answer.